# Delete/Remove the Dynamically created Textboxes in Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, controls

I have a Code Which will Create a Textbox During Runtime.

```
 public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox AddNewTextBox()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            dynamicTextBoxes.Add($"tb{cLeft}", txt);
            txt.Top = cLeft * 25;
            txt.Left = 100;
            txt.Multiline = true;
            txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100,100);
            txt.BringToFront();
            txt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;


            txt.Text = "TextBox " + this.cLeft.ToString();
            cLeft = cLeft + 1;
            return txt;
        }
```

i also added the control into the dictionary

```
 private Dictionary<string, TextBox> dynamicTextBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
```

now i want to delete the textbox.

I am using this code to delete/remove the textbox.

```
dynamicTextBoxes[$"tb{cLeft - 1}"].Dispose();
```

But this line of code is removing only the last created textbox.

My question is how can i remove all or selected textboxes one by one on each button click.

Comment: and what is  the error message?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Page 2 does not contain any definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting the first argument of type page2 could fine(Are you missing a directive or reference)

Comment: "when I use `System.Windows.Forms. ...` in WPF" - that is the problem.

Comment: In what world do you think error messages aren't useful

Comment: A WPF window does not have a Controls property.  Embedding a winforms control requires a WindowsFormsHost.  There are very few practical reasons to favor a winforms TextBox over a WPF TextBox, you need to throw the mental switch and start writing WPF code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman can you please review the question.

Comment: I don't see the point - it's still tagged WPF...  Otherwise, you just need something smarter for cLeft-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to use `Children` instead of `Controls` and secondly you should add controls to some container like `Grid`,`StackPanel` ,...

```
System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
yourGrid.Children.Add(txt);
```

Please note that namespace should be [`System.Windows.Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls(v=vs.110).aspx) here.